# EF Code First self rating by DataAnnotations or fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have one class:

```
[Table(nameof(User), Schema = "Administration")]
public class User : IBaseModel
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    #region IBaseModel

    public int AddedBy { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AddedBy")]
    public virtual User UserAddedBy { get; set; }

    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ModifiedBy")]
    public virtual User UserModifiedBy { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

I try create self relation for this table (who AddedBy and who ModifiedBy item)

When my class look like above and I try use `Add-Migration init` on Package Manager Console it returns error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'abc.Administration.User' and 'abc.Administration.User'.
>   The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured
>   using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

after this error I try use fluent API and on method `OnModelCreating` (in my context) I wrote:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Administration.User>().HasOptional(e => e.UserAddedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.AddedBy);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Administration.User>().HasOptional(e => e.UserModifiedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.ModifiedBy);
    }
```

and again try `Add-Migration init` but again I saw error message:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> abc.User_UserAddedBy: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential
>   constraint in Role 'User_UserAddedBy_Target' in relationship
>   'User_UserAddedBy'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent
>   Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.
>   abc.User_UserModifiedBy: : Multiplicity conflicts with the referential
>   constraint in Role 'User_UserModifiedBy_Target' in relationship
>   'User_UserModifiedBy'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent
>   Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.

I found information to add `Required` to attribute before virtual properites but it did not help.

Comment: Did you try nullable ints? try this `int?` instead of `int`.

Comment: DataAnnotations nullable `int` they generate the first of the indicated errors, but fluent API works correctly. But I prefer DataAnnotations and I imagine the not nullable `ForeignKey` he was watching over connections.

Comment: There are no other classes, these are two personal relations to the same table

Comment: I noticed so I erased the comment, I'll see if what I can do.

Comment: How about trying 
`[ForeignKey("UserAddedBy ")]  
public int? AddedBy { get; set; }
    
    public virtual User UserAddedBy { get; set; }

 [ForeignKey("UserModifiedBy ")]
    public int? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
   
    public virtual User UserModifiedBy { get; set; }`

Comment: Your code they generate the first of the indicated errors. The key is here nullabel `int`. I understand that non nullabel int is wrong e.g table is empty and I want to add first element (e.g user administrator) in this case what id enter to AddedBy and ModifiedBy. Maybe there is no point in thinking about it, unless there is a way to do it. But I don't understand why fluent API is working and DataAnnotations no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the clarifications provided, you can do the following:

1. Disable enforcing the Foreign Key(FK)
2. Add a dummy user, you could use a name like "System", give it an imposible id like -1.
3. Make system be it's own UserAddedBy and UserModifiedBy
4. Enable enforcing FK.
   Now you can add users with System as their UserModifiedBy and UserAddedBy.

This way the only "cheated" in user will be System, which, in my humble opinion, is an OK trade-off.

Comment: I used your suggested solution and everything is working but if only I use fluent API. I dont know why.

Answer (score 2):

> Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are non-nullable,
>   multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.

Try using `int?` instead of `int`.